# animating images in css 3D to move diagonally across the page

Tags: html, css, animation, translate3d

I am trying to animate some clouds on my website so they move diagonally across the page (starting off screen on the top left, ending off screen on the bottom right).

So far I have them moving from left to right but i'm not sure how to use translate3D to get them to move in this direction. Here's a site that shows what I want to achieve: http://futurewatercity.com/ (you have to click through to their map using the arrow)

and here is my code:

```
<div class="sky">
  <div class="cloud cloud01"></div>
  <div class="cloud cloud02"></div>
</div>

.cloud {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  transform: scale(0.25);
  position: absolute;
  background: url(file://C:/Users/Sara/Documents/ExploreCanterbury/img/clouds01.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.cloud01 {
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
  transform: scale(0.35);
  animation: drift 25s linear infinite;
}

.cloud02 {
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  animation: drift 35s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes drift {
  from {transform: translateX(-355px);}
  to {transform: translateX(1350px);}
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want a transform for this...rather animate the positioning